# WSOD -- Website Down

Tags: wordpress

So my website was running smooth, no changes made in last 6 months,

Suddenly I am getting a white screen when opening my website

website: http://www.nicefitcareers.com

Problems:

1) Website not loading up

2) Can't access the http://example/wp-admin/ -- same white screen

Steps Taken So far

1) Enabled error reporting in wp-config -- set to true, still cant see any debug output on screen

2) Disabled Plugins folder completely -- renamed it to plugins_bkup

3) Disabled theme folder too -- renamed it to backup

4) Did code restore from old snapshot -- but still no luck..

I am running a blog also on the same server that is working smooth

Blog: http://www.nicefitcareers.com/Blog

I have no clue what went wrong and how to debug it, completely clueless!

Please help!!

Comment: You are doing everything right, as shown here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors. One thing you may not have tried is check your db hasn't reached its limit and is now shut off. Check your webhost for this, or use your control panel if you have access to it. Also can you ftp in? look for a .maintenance file in your home directory. It gets left over sometimes from updates and if it remains, your site gives the WSOD.

Comment: No limit on the Db.. 

Don't have any .maintenance file .. I can do ftp, I do have access to it! 

I am sitting on godaddy delux hosting, so bandwidth should not be an issue!

Comment: Make sure you can see hidden files on your server via ftp. WSOD happens a lot of the time from the database going or your site's memory usage being used up, but this memory usage has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I see in the page source of `nicefitcareers.com`

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -2595px"><a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
</div>
```

If `nicefitcareers.com` and your `nicefitcareers.com/blog` are two different WordPress installs, the one at `nicefitcareers.com` probably got hacked.

Carefully follow [FAQ My site was hacked - WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Comment: Hey Mark, I did see this, but unable to make out anything from it, I tried restoring from a old backup, but same result!

Comment: and Yes, both the websites are running on two different installations of wordpress!

Comment: Try replacing all core Wordpress files and folders (do not replace wp-config.php or wp-content) in root (such as index.php, wp-login.php, wp-admin, wp-includes, etc) and see if the site comes back up. If it does, then follow thw instructions in the hacking link above.

Comment: Doing it now! uploading files!

Comment: Thanks Marks, uploaded all the files from backup, and its working again pheww.. Took the backup of the production files, now will go through the debugging process what went wrong! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, as shown here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors. One thing you may not have tried is check your db hasn't reached its limit and is now shut off. Check your webhost for this, or use your control panel if you have access to it. Also can you ftp in? look for a .maintenance file in your home directory. It gets left over sometimes from updates and if it remains, your site gives the WSOD.